# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Possible target folders

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-download-manager

When having `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I'd expect to have right to write all over the filesystem (eg. `/sdcard`,`/storage/emulated/0`,`/storage/sdcard0`,`/mnt/sdcard`,...)

But because of different internal FS structure, I'm not really able to tell what are allowed folders on target device.

Currently I use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` to get downloads folder, but this is in my opinion not the only folder I'm allowed to use.

So two questions follow:

1. Is there way to find out what folders I can write wih such permission?
2. When using DownloadManager, are possible target folders sae as for the first question?

Comment: Use [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

Comment: You should not worry about various paths you have mentioned (`/sdcard`, `/storage/emulated/0`, `/storage/sdcard0`, `/mnt/sdcard`). Normally, they all point to the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get available external storage directory.

You will get the Android external storage directory. This directory may not currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has happened. You can determine its current state with `getExternalStorageState()`.

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Comment: This returns only one directory, is it the only one I'm allowed to use?

Comment: This is the root directory. You can read/write any content within this directory or its sub-directory.

Comment: I mentioned i my question, there is many mount-points for example in my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and in some way I can read/write to other directories.

Answer (score 0):

For android, there's only one external storage, the one it returns via `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, so you should use that by default.

But, the public mount points usually have a `rw` permission for user processes, where your app is running, so you can write there as well. Get root permissions and you can write pretty much anywhere.